# Doctrine optional OneToOne mapping

Tags: orm, doctrine, mapping, one-to-one

I'm trying to create a optional OneToOne mapping in Doctrine.

I have a table with all cities and zip codes available (this table shouldn't be changed), and I have a table with addresses and a mapped city. But sometimes I don't want to add City to my Address at the beginning (maybe later on it will). But when I don't add a City to the Address the persist on the Address gives me a Reflection Exception because there is no object like 'null' , which should be de City object.

I don't want to add an empty city every time into the database, because there should nothing be added or deleted to the city table.

Any suggestions? Or what am I missing?

```
class Address{
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="City")
 * @JoinColumn(name="city_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
  private $city = '';
```

**Possible solutions I considered:**

- Create an empty city object in the db and assign this always to newly created Address objects (might cause a lot of overhead)
- Create a ManyToMany relationship with an array of cities, so there can be zero or more cities added (I can restrict the multitude of cities in my Address object) but then I need a mapping table...

Comment: I know I come to the party very later... but could not resist. Are you sure this is a OneToOne association ? Surely the same city is likely to be used in many different addresses?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just simply add `nullable=true` to `@JoinColumn` annotation

Comment: any way to make this work for a multi-column join (ie @JoinColumns).  I have tried but without any luck...

Comment: Unfortunately it generates INSERT INTO query with empty parameter and causes an error: `'INSERT INTO message_conversation (title, lastMessage_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [43]` - the second param (one to one) is missing.

Comment: It does not work for me. I added nullable=true but no success. Are there anyway to make one to one relationship as optionnal ?